# Capture specific modifier key

Tags: c#, winforms, capture, key, modifier

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN, the `Key Value` for Left Control is 162. How can I determine if this key is pressed in code? At the moment, everytime I try and handle a keypress, I get the value `17` which is just a generic control key. Is there a way to differentiate the two? I've tried overriding `ProcessCmdKey` and handling `PreviewKeyDown` of a Textbox, but they both return 17 instead of 162. I need to do this for all modifier keys and before I end up hardcoding the values, is there a better alternative to capture these in code?

Edit: Code added. To clarify, I want to retrieve the 162 number and not just find an alternative way of differentiating the modifiers.

```
private void PortfolioNameTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    var val = e.KeyValue; //17 when control is pressed and not 162

}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    //msg.Wparam = 17
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to capture the keypress (I assume you want to capture it from within your form and not globally)?

Comment: I've added the code and yes, just the form.

Comment: In WinForms I think you're out of luck. You can only deal with the keycodes that are passed to your application. A potential workaround would be to setup a global key hook and check that the current application is your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messr Passant [answered](http://www.msarm.com/FAQ/Question/a61c6a5d-88ed-4621-9019-5698b5c846e5) this many moons ago.

Would be nice if the KeyEventArgs included it, but nonetheless, you can achieve it like this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

    private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ctrl:{0}, LCtrl:{1}, RCtrl:{2}",
        GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) < 0,
        GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LControlKey) < 0,
        GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RControlKey) < 0);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, just read your comment... you COULD get your magic 162 using that approach with brute force. E.g, if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LControlKey) < 0) return (int)Keys.LControlKey, but not ideal